# How to merge a K8s Configmap to a Secret (or two secrets together)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using Helm w/ Kubernetes and am trying to add data that I have in an existing Configmap to an existing secret. The reason for this, is that there is a property on a CRD that I need to set which only takes in a single secret key ref. The existing secret is created by Vault, and the existing Configmap is configured in the Helm chart in plain text. For reasons that I won't get into, we cannot include the content of the configmap into the Vault secret entry, so I MUST be able to merge these two into a secret.

I've tried searching for this, but most answers I see involve creating an initContainer and setting up a volume, but unfortunately I don't think this will work for my situation. I just need a single secret that I can reference in a CRD and problem solved. Is this possible using Kubernetes/Helm?

My fallback plan is to create my own CRD and associated controller to merge the configmap data and the secret's data and basically create a new secret, but it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware of there is not way to do this in kubernetes.

The only solution that I can see would be to implement some tool yourself. With something like [kopf](https://kopf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you could implement a simple operator that listen for the creation/update of a specific secret and configmap, get their data and merge it into a new secret.
Using an operator allows you to handle all the cases that might occur during the life of your resources, such as when your new secret is deleted or updated, etc.

Comment: Thanks @ITChap. This looks like Kubebuilder except simpler and in Python. Should be what I need. Main thing is I needed to know there wasn't a K8s native way of doing this that I was missing. Marking as solved!